# Are these SQL statements equivalent - case when vs. NVL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My colleague has the following SQL statement executed in Redshift:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN P.PRED_VAL IS NULL THEN R.SCORE_VAL
        ELSE P.PRED_VAL
    END AS FINAL_SCORE
FROM RESULT R
INNER JOIN PREDICTION P
    ON R.ID = P.ID;
```

Is there any context in which the result of that statement wouldn't be the same as `NVL(P.PRED_VAL, R.SCORE_VAL)`?

Comment: What database are you using, please?

Comment: Sorry - thanks for pointing that out. Redshift

Comment: Those two expressions (your case expression and NVL/COALESCE) should work exactly the same.

Comment: short answer is that yes. they are equivalent. however, may i suggest `coalesce` instead of `nvl` for better standards compliance.

Comment: Yeah, that was my impression too. Exactly feeling. I can't see why it wouldn't be written using the more concise nvl

Comment: The second query is invalid for PostgreSQL - I removed the tag.

Comment: po-TAY-to, po-TAH-to - They're equivalent ways of expressing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nvl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html) is simply a non-standard name for the SQL standard `coalesce` function.

There is no functional difference between your `case` and your `nvl`, except that `nvl` is non-standard. Use `coalesce`.